# Is there a way to embed an editable buffer within a buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Let's say I have a file, `who.txt`, and in that file is just the word "joe".
And in another file, `won.txt` with the text "won the lottery".

Now, I want to `insert-file` `who.txt` into the beginning of `won.txt` and the result should be:
"joe won the lottery."

Is there a way to replace `joe` in that sentence with `sam` and have it auto update `who.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: no.

The long answer: yes.  When inserting the text from who.txt (using `insert-file-contents`), you could add a `modification-hooks` text property on it with a function that updates who.txt on modifications of the propertized region.

But that doesn't feel like a good idea.  What's the problem you are trying to solve.  There's probably a better way.

Comment: I feel like you summarized emacs with "Short answer: no.  Long answer: yes."  :-)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not clear why you need this functionality. If you want to embed an editable file, the `freex` minor mode may be useful. https://code.google.com/p/emacs-freex/ You can watch the screencast and see if it fits your needs.